# In Java, is new always new?

Tags: java

Is there any way in Java that a statement like

```
Thing thing = new Thing();
```

could *not* result in a new object being created (i.e. any way that `thing` could end up pointing to an already-existing object)?

Comment: Why do you ask? Are you getting strange behavior somewhere?

Comment: No strange behaviour. Just curious - I was reading about the Integer(int i) constructor - the point being made was that the static method Integer.valueOf(int i) might be better since it will reuse objects as necessary - I wanted to check that it was impossible, not just unconventional, for a constructor to do the reuse thing.

Comment: Yep, it's impossible. In C++, you could override the `new` operator, but you can't in Java. Which does not make me sad.

Comment: @ mmyers: Say that again after you've had to implement something like the Flyweight pattern. Overloading operator new() can come in mightily handy. Not that I ever had to do that in ten years of C++ work.

Answer (score 16):

The `new` operator allocates new heap space and calls the constructor. You will always get a new object that way (unless, as others pointed out, an Exception is thrown in the constructor).

The thing is a little different with static methods that return a reference, such as `Integer.valueOf()` which re-uses objects from an internal pool if possible.

Comment: Yep and it's even a recommended pattern in the great Joshua Bloch's "Effective Java"

Answer (score 6):

If the constructor for Thing throws an exception, the object isn't created. However, `thing` will never point to another existing instance of Thing.

Comment: nor `null` values. It's strange to see code like `Thing t = new Thing(); if (t == null ) ...` - it will never happen

Answer (score 4):

Several people are saying that an object won't be created if the constructor throws an exception.  I would just like to point out that this is not true.  As an example, take a look at this very bad code:

```
public class Test {
    static int count;

    static Set<Test> set = new HashSet<Test>();

    int id = count++;


    public Test() {
        set.add(this);
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            try {
                new Test();
            } catch(Exception e) {
            }
        }
        System.out.println(set);
    }


    public String toString() {
        return "Test[" + id + "]";
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
[Test[0], Test[1], Test[2], Test[4], Test[3]]
```

`new` creates a new object EVERY TIME.

Answer (score 3):

Using `new` will always result in a new object being allocated and created.  However, you might be referring to the concept of *interning*, where objects and stored in a pool and can be reused to save on space.  For a good example, see this article on [String interning](http://javatechniques.com/public/java/docs/basics/string-equality.html)  in Java.

Answer (score 1):

New is always new (maybe with some exceptions for primitive wrappers), but if reusing objects is a desired behaviour there are ways to do that through certain design patterns (singleton, factory, pool etc.).

Comment: Primitive wrappers (also called boxed primitives) follow the same rules as any other class: if you use a constructor to create one, you always get a new instance. However, autoboxing doesn't necessarily create a unique object each time because it uses a factory method instead of a constructor.

Comment: Did I say somethin different?

Comment: New is always new. There are no exceptions, even for primitive wrappers.

Answer (score 0):

No, in the case there's no space in memory for it, you should get an OutOfMemoryError.

Of course, there could be other exceptions thrown by the Thing constructor.

Comment: hmmm, why isn't that an OutOfMemoryError? Just interested.

Comment: @CD1 @Tim Corrected the mistake. I knew it was something like that. my bad

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly.

The definition of new is *to allocate and initialize a new object*.

I guess you might be able store a static reference to a object, and then clone it to make a new object, but that object would still be new.

Since you cannot modify the value of `this` (otherwise you could just say something like `this = oldObject` in your constructor), the only way you could do this is to throw an exception, like has been mentioned before.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know it's not like C++ where you can overload `operator new` or do placement new or other allocator things. (but I'm not familiar with the JLS)

Answer (score 0):

new always creates new object. In java you can't reuse object using new. Really this leads to performance issue in certain java class. For e.g. Boolean class can practically stores only two values (true or false), still a user can create multiple objects with same value using new.

Answer (score 0):

No.

After executing that line of code `thing` will never reference an object that existed before that line.

Answer (score 0):

The call to `new` can fail if this is the first time you are referring to the class and if the class has static blocks that fail to initialize. I have experienced behaviors wherein any runtime errors that occur in a static block or constructor will result in the new call throwing a ClassNotFound Exception in the context of usage within the websphere application server. The websphere class loader apparently rejects the class from loading because of the runtime exception.

Answer (score -1):

In Java, the only thing I can think of is using the Singleton pattern. This would not create multiple new instances of Thing, but rather an instance of the same object every time.

Comment: Any time you use `new`, you're creating a new instance. Period. With the Singleton pattern, you're calling `SingletonClass.getInstance()`, not `new SingletonClass()`.